# MVC mudar de partial view com control select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou a fazer uma aplicação em que o usuário escolhe uma opção e é mostrado um formulário diferente para cada uma dessas opções.

O meu problema é que quando altero a opção, não consigo alterar para a partial view correspondente.

**Na pasta Shared criei 4 Partial Views**

- _partialView1
- _partialView2
- _partialView3
- _partialView4

*Apenas inseri uma tag  com o número!*

**No HTML + Jquery:**

*Também tentei fazer um append("@Html.Partial("_partialView1")")
, mas não resultou...*

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dropdown").change(function () {
                var str = "";
                $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                    str = $(this).text();
                    if (str == "OP 1") {
                        $("#MyPartialView").load("/_partialView1");
                    }
                    else if (str == "OP 2") {
                        $("#MyPartialView").load("/_partialView2");
                    }
                    else if (str == "OP 3") {
                        $("#MyPartialView").load("/_partialView3");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#MyPartialView").load("/_partialView4");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

```html
<select id="dropdown" class="form-control col-sm-2 mb-5 mt-5" name="opcao">
    <option>OP 1</option>
    <option>OP 2</option>
    <option>OP 3</option>
    <option>OP 4</option>
</select>

<div id="MyPartialView">
    @Html.Partial("_partialView1")
</div>
```

Comment: não é assim que funciona uma partial view, não tem como carregar uma partial view ( C# ) com JQuery. Eu sugiro que você traga todas as partial views e depois controle a visibilidade delas através do JQuery será mais produtivo e simples de ser feito.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que seja mais facil renderizar todas as partials view e controlar a visibilidade delas através do Dropdown pelo JQuery. Por exemplo: ( https://jsfiddle.net/1mL94qu7/ )

Seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

***Seu HTML***

```
<div id="MyPartialViewContainer">

    <div id="PartialView1">
        @Html.Partial("_partialView1")
    </div>
    
    <div id="PartialView2">
        @Html.Partial("_partialView2")
    </div>
    
    <div id="PartialView3">
        @Html.Partial("_partialView3")
    </div>
    
    <div id="PartialView4">
        @Html.Partial("_partialView4")
    </div>

</div>
```

***Seu script JQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // reseta as partials views como hide no carregamento da página
        $("#PartialView1").hide();
        $("#PartialView2").hide();
        $("#PartialView3").hide();
        $("#PartialView4").hide();

    $("#dropdown").change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str = $(this).text();
            if (str == "OP 1") {
                $("#PartialView1").show();
                $("#PartialView2").hide();
                $("#PartialView3").hide();
                $("#PartialView4").hide();
            }
            else if (str == "OP 2") {
                $("#PartialView1").hide();
                $("#PartialView2").show();
                $("#PartialView3").hide();
                $("#PartialView4").hide();
            }
            else if (str == "OP 3") {
                $("#PartialView1").hide();
                $("#PartialView2").hide();
                $("#PartialView3").show();
                $("#PartialView4").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#PartialView1").hide();
                $("#PartialView2").hide();
                $("#PartialView3").hide();
                $("#PartialView4").show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```